# Address Autocomplete on Standard Salesforce via V

Tags: address, autocomplete

I am trying to enable Address Autcomplete on Standard Salesforce via Visualforce page. I am using this code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountDedupeController" tabstyle="Account" showHeader="true">
    <style type="text/css">input[type="text"]:disabled {display: none;}</style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyBrRb6IVhS3CMgxll5fZiauduGdxzpG1cAsigned_in=true&libraries=places"></script> 
     <apex:form id="searchform">
      <apex:sectionheader title="Account Google Places Sample" subtitle="{!if(Account.Id==null,'New Account',Account.Name)}">
      </apex:sectionheader>   
      <apex:pageblock mode="edit" id="AccountPB" title="Account Edit">
         <apex:pageBlockSection id="searchblocksection" columns="3" title="Address Search" >
             <apex:outputLabel value="Global Address Search" for="field" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
             <apex:inputText label="" size="60" id="addressfield">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" oncomplete="SetStateCode()" rerender="Billing_StateCode"/>
             </apex:inputText>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageblocksection id="AddressInformationPBS" title="Address Information" columns="2" collapsible="true">    
             <apex:inputfield taborderhint="1" value="{!Account.Name}" id="name"></apex:inputfield>
             <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
             <apex:inputfield taborderhint="2" value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" id="street"></apex:inputfield>
             <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
             <apex:inputfield taborderhint="3" value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" id="postal_code"></apex:inputfield>
             <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
             <apex:inputfield taborderhint="4" value="{!Account.BillingCity}" id="locality"></apex:inputfield>
             <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
             <apex:inputfield taborderhint="5" value="{!Account.BillingCountryCode}" id="country"/>
             <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
             <apex:inputfield taborderhint="6" value="{!Account.BillingStateCode}" id="Billing_StateCode"/>
             <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
             <apex:inputField taborderhint="10" value="{!Account.Phone}" required="True" id="international_phone_number"></apex:inputfield>

             <apex:inputText label=" " id="street_number" disabled="True"/>
             <apex:inputText label=" " id="route" disabled="True"/>
             <apex:inputText label=" " id="statecode" disabled="True"/>
             <apex:inputText label=" " id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="True"/>
             <apex:inputText label=" " id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled="True"/>
         </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>

        <script>  
        // initialize the google places components
        initialize();
        // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
        // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.
        //var autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            name: 'long_name',
            international_phone_number: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            postal_town: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
            country: 'short_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            street_number: 'long_name',
            street: 'long_name',
            website: 'long_name',
        };

        function initialize() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
            // to geographical location types.
            var input = document.getElementById('{!$Component.searchform.AccountPB.searchblocksection.addressfield}');
            var options = {types: []};
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
            // populate the address fields in the form.
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                // call back function after user clicks on a location
                fillInAddress();
            });
        }

        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            var route = '', street_number = '', administrative_area_level_1 = '';
            var administrative_area_level_2 = '', country = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                // set the country
                if (addressType === 'country') {
                    country = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                }
                // set the street name
                if (addressType === 'route') {
                    route = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                }
                // set the street number
                if (addressType === 'street_number') {
                    street_number = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                }
                // set the state
                if (addressType === 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                    administrative_area_level_1 = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                }
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var elem_id = '{!$Component.searchform.AccountPB.AddressInformationPBS.}'+":"+addressType;
                    document.getElementById(elem_id).value = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                }
            }

            // set the name of the address
            var elem_id = '{!$Component.searchform.AccountPB.AddressInformationPBS.}'+":"+'name';
            document.getElementById(elem_id).value = place['name'];

            var elem_id = '{!$Component.searchform.AccountPB.AddressInformationPBS.}'+":"+'street';
            document.getElementById(elem_id).value = (country === 'FR') ? street_number + ' ' + route : route + ' ' + street_number;

            // set the phone number
            var elem_id = '{!$Component.searchform.AccountPB.AddressInformationPBS.}'+":"+'international_phone_number';
            document.getElementById(elem_id).value = place['international_phone_number'];

            var elem_id = '{!$Component.searchform.AccountPB.AddressInformationPBS.}'+":"+'Billing_StateCode';
            document.getElementById(elem_id).value = administrative_area_level_1;
        }

    $('html').bind('keypress', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){return false;}
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

But the following error appears:

Could not resolve field 'BillingCountryCode' from  value binding '{!Account.BillingCountryCode}' in page Address_Autocomplete

Do you have any idea why?

Alternatively, is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Try using 'BillingCountry' instead of 'BillingCountryCode'....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `BillingCountryCode` will only be available in your org if you have State and Country Picklists turned on. If your org uses plain-text fields for the State and Country fields, you'll just have `BillingCountry` (and `BillingState` rather than `BillingStateCode`) available.